# Data sync check among two SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, synchronization

We've two SQL server database. The source server has data populated from an external system and a destination database on a remote server (used by a web app). There's an SSIS package which maps column from source tables to destination (column names differ) and populates data to maintain the sync.

Now, to ensure that both the database are in sync for which we've an SP which shows record count and for some parent-child relationships it shows child count for each parent record (i.e. Brandwise Item count). Someone has to logon to both the servers, execute the SP and get the data manually. Then compare the results to ensure that both the db are in sync.

Now, to automate this process, we've done the following-

> 1. Add the destination server as a "[Linked Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx)"
> 2. Use "EXEC msdb.dbo.[sp_send_dbmail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307%28SQL.90%29.aspx)" along with "@attach_query_result_as_file =1"
> 3. Create an SSIS job which will execute the email SP for both the servers
>
> So, this is how we get two emails which has query results attached to
>   it. And then comparing the text files completes the db sync check.

*I believe this can be made better - now that we're able to access the destination server as a linked server.* Its my first time so I'd request some experienced guys to share their approach, probably something beyond a join query with the linked server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have access to server as Linked server you can directly run query and compare data.

Please check [this](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2004/11/10/2737.aspx)

You can modify SSIS jobs to send mails based on this query result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following query which is a simple version and gives me differences of both the sides -

```
(Select s.Title, s.Description from ERPMasterBrand as s   EXCEPT
Select d.Title, d.Description from MasterBrand as d)
UNION
(Select s.Title, s.Description from MasterBrand as s      EXCEPT
Select d.Title, d.Description from ERPMasterBrand as d)
```

Any better suggestions? I've tested and it gives desired results - hope I'm not being misguided :-) by my own solution.